# Displaying the pdf file in any one of the pdf app downloaded in my ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, pdf

Is there any way to redirect directly to an IOS apps to display my pdf file by any one of the PDF editor app downloaded into my IOS App?

please give me any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
 NSString *stringURL = @"ibooks://";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];`
```

You can get help from [this link.](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)

Modified code for opening a pdf file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDocumentInteractionController *controller;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction)openDocument:(id)sender {

NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"typo_tips" withExtension:@"pdf"];
self.controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];
self.controller.delegate = self;
self.controller.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";

[self.controller presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: Hello pawan thanx for the reply...so,in @"ibooks://" after // do i nedd to add any link???

Comment: you have your pdf file at some url or its in document directory?      if you have it in document directory then get the path of file and add to string url.

Comment: yeah i have done it but it displays nothing to me...do i need to add any other code to display the PDF file???

Comment: NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"typo_tips" ofType:@"pdf"];                                                        NSString *stringURL = @"ibooks:/";
    NSString *stringURL1 = [stringURL stringByAppendingString:file];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

Comment: check modified code for it. its a proper way to open a document type in ios (recommended by apple developer).